# Datagridview image to picture box

Tags: vb.net

Good day!.,
i was trying to display/call an image from specific datagridrow to a picturebox but i could'nt find any right code for it.

i found a simple code but it didnt work for me, here's the link of the code: http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.com/2016/03/vb-net-datagridview-image-to-picturebox.html

and i got this error from catch:

## unable to cast object of type 'system.byte ' to type 'system.drawing.bitmap'

this part of the code is causing me troubles.

```vb
img = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value
```

here is the whole code

```vb
Private Sub Student_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Student.CellClick
       Dim index As Integer
       Dim ms As New MemoryStream
       Dim img As Bitmap

       index = e.RowIndex
       Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
       selectedRow = Student.Rows(index)
       Try
           img = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value
           img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
           Pic1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
       Catch ex As Exception

           MsgBox(ex.Message)
       End Try

       idnum.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
       fname.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
       midname.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
       lname.Text = selectedRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
       course.Text = selectedRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
       address.Text = selectedRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
       Contactnum.Text = selectedRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
       rfid.Text = selectedRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()




   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Byte2Image(ByVal ByteArr() As Byte) As Bitmap
    Dim ImageStream As MemoryStream
    Try
        If ByteArr.GetUpperBound(0) > 0 Then
            ImageStream = New MemoryStream(ByteArr)
            ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ImageStream)
            Return bmp
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

**Using:**

```
Dim img = Byte2Image(selectedRow.Cells(0).Value)
If img IsNot Nothing
   Pic1.Image = img
End If
```

Comment: Whoa! you're a life savior! thanks for small and simple code its 100 working!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it with Item instead of Cells. So you would then just write

```
    Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
       selectedRow = Student.Rows(index)
    img = selectedRow.Item(0)
```

Hopefully this helps. Otherwise just ask anything since I've done something pretty simular over the last days.

Comment: Oh jeah sorry I mixed up datagridView and DataGridViewRow there. But since you found a Answer I think I don't need to write a functional Example anymore or ?